# Moving cursor by one character instead of one cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Title says it all. If I edit cell in excel and press left/right arrow then my cell selection jumps to corresponding cell instead of moving one character left/right as you'd expect in edition mode.

I tried some shortcuts, like `alt`+`arrow`, `ctrl`+`arrow`, `shift`+`arrow` and I don't even know how to google it because I can't find anything helpful...

I'm aware that's totally basic problem but would make my life much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in the cell, you can hit the **F2** key and that will allow you to move around within the cell.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) anyway, quite stupid and non intuitive but it's not the first thing that surprises me in excel...

Comment: You can also click up in the formula editing box above the cell grid.